# The specified package is not valid Windows package. Error: 0x800f0805

Tags: windows-server-2016, dhcp-server

I installed Windows Server 2016 on VirtualBox, and now I am trying to install DHCP server on my Windows Server 2016 machine, but I got an error. I set this machine as a Domain Controller before, so I thought this situation may cause the error. I searched it on web, and found a solution. Then I deleted some language packages from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\PackageDetect`, but it didn't solve the problem. What should I do to solve this?

***The error message is:***

The request to add or remove feautures on the specified server failed. Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed. The specified package is not valid Windows package. Error: 0x800f0805

***A screenshot of the error message can be seen below:***

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export and Import `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages` registry in the problem server from another server of same OS and build.

You can see the difference in both the severs just by looking at the `Packages` key.

Comment: I have googled and tested soooooo many things and this simple and smart solution saved my life!
PS: Works also in 2024 with Win Server 2022